# What are the birthday rewards for Xbox Live's "MyAchievements" promotion?

Tags: achievements, xbox-network

This week, Xbox Live released their promotion thing that turns achievement points into direct benefits per tier. Each tier says you get a "A Special Gift* during your birthday month." Does anyone have any idea what this special gift is? My Birthday is next month so I'm fairly interested to know what will randomly show up on my account :P.

Source: http://rewards.xbox.com/myachievements/

Comment: I don't think the gift has been seen by anyone yet, but it's value is $0.25 - so I'm betting on an avatar prop.

Comment: I'll know when its Oct 16 :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just got my birthday reward email from Xbox Live. It said the following:

> Hi Klokworkk,
>
> Happy Birthday Month!
>
> Congratulations! This month you'll be another year wiser. But what's a
>   birthday without a sweet surprise? Try this: Enjoy 20 Microsoft Points
>   as our gift to you. Use it toward anything you wish in the Xbox LIVE
>   Marketplace. Your birthday Microsoft Points will be automatically
>   deposited into your Xbox LIVE account by the 15th of the month.
>
> It's just one of the fun extras you get for reaching CONTENDER,
>   CHAMPION or LEGEND status on MyAchievements from Xbox LIVE Rewards.
>   Now, take a deep breath and blow out those candles!
>
> Hoping your birthday wishes come true,
>
> Xbox LIVE Rewards Squad

So it looks like they just give you 20 MSPs for your birthday. I guess it is better than nothing, lol.

Comment: What level (CONTENDER, CHAMPION or LEGEND) are you at?

Comment: I'm at legend level.

Comment: Wow, 20 MSP for a legendary player. ¬_¬

Comment: Yea, kinda what I said, lol. Guess it is better than nothing though?

Comment: 4 more birthdays and I can buy myself a t-shirt for my avatar.