# Not getting Microsoft Points for my birthday month reward

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I signed up for Xbox Live Rewards and my birthday is this month. My friend on the first week of his birthday month, got Microsoft Points for however many Gamerscore he has. How do I get my reward and how do I make sure I am signed up and that everything's ready to go?

Comment: that my friend is what we call a troll.

Answer (score 2):

It's [based on your Gamerscore](http://rewards.xbox.com/myachievements/). You need at-least a 3000 Gamerscore to get anything.

Also, In order to qualify for the Birthday Gift, you must be Gold on the 1st of March. If neither one of these are met you do not get any Birthday reward.

I also hate to break it you but according to [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86130/what-are-the-birthday-rewards-for-xbox-lives-myachievements-promotion) you only get like 20 points, not sure where you friend got the idea you get your Gamerscore in points.

Comment: Yeah, I just had my birthday last month. The 'Birthday Gift' they give is 20 ms points. However, I usually get 200+ ms points each month since I spend a lot on the XBL market place (1% points back based on gamer score of over 10,000 but under 25,000).